# $e^{-x} (\sin(6x))$ find roots of the derivative.

Tags: calculus

> Find roots of the derivative of $e^{-x} (\sin(6x))$.

I could use some help with my calculus homework. I am having a hard time finding the roots. Here is a picture of my current graph.

[image]

Here is the derivative, I used the product rule;
$$ \frac{d}{dx}=e^{-x}(\sin(6x)) = 6e^{-x} (\cos(6x)) - e^{-x}(\sin(6x))$$

To get started I have tried to find the period of the $\cos(6x) = \frac{2\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}$  I usually divide the period by 4, which gave me $\frac{\pi}{12}$.  Then I can add
$\frac{\pi}{12}$ together 4 times.  Each increment of $\frac{\pi}{12}$ gives me all the x values that I need.  In this case it isn't working the way it has in the past.  I was thinking, the amplitude is now an exponential function, which is a curved line.  Usually the amplitude up until now has been a constant number like 3 or 4.  Since the line is curved maybe it travels a different length and this is reason why.  I did graph $e^{-x}$ and $-e^{-x}$.  These are the dotted lines.  Each appears to come close to the crest and dips of the cos function.  However I can not for the life of me find the roots unless I try to guess.

Most of my thought up until this point has been based on the equation $a \cos(bx-c) +d$.  I thought this general from of a trigonometry equation would lead the way but now I am second guessing it and would like to some help how to find the roots of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The periodicity approach isn't a bad one, but in this case, I think it's more trouble than it's worth. Your differentiation looks correct, and factoring the $e^{-x}$ out of the expression and setting it equal to $0$ yields $e^{-x}(6\cos(6x)-\sin(6x))=0$. Since $e^{-x}$ never equals $0$, the problem basically reduces to solving $6\cos(6x)-\sin(6x)=0$. This equation can be solved with basic algebra:

$6\cos(6x)=\sin(6x)$

$6=\tan(6x)$

$x=\frac{1}6\tan^{-1}(6)+\frac{\pi}{6}n$ for integer values of $n$ (there are infinite solutions due to the periodicity of $\tan$).

The $e^{-x}$ factor changes the behavior of the function elsewhere, but the position of the roots stays the same.

Comment: You're right, I should have clarified that it was the principle solution. I'll revise it now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is the period of the function.  I forgot how to find the period of tangent too.  This was very helpful; I was very lost.  Period of tan = $\frac{\pi}{B}$. Thanks again.